# how to write group-by query SQL with quantity unit conversion?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, subquery

```
Stock

Product  Quantity  Unit 
-------------------------------
001       5        box
001       10       bottle
001       60       gallon


Conversion

Unit1     Unit2    Rate
----------------------
box       bottle    20
bottle    gallon    30

Unit1 = Unit2 * Rate
```

How to write SQL query to sum(quantity) in certain unit (such as bottle in the example)?

```
select product, sum(quantity * ....) from Stock group by product
```

can a database function such as getRate(unit1, unit2) do the job? how about the performance?

Comment: what's the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expand the conversion table so it has all combinations.  This is a one time effort, but you need to add rows like this:

```
Unit1     Unit2    Rate
----------------------
box       bottle    20
bottle    gallon    30
gallon    bottle    1/30
```

Then you can use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT s.product, SUM(s.quantity * coalesce(c.rate, 1))
FROM stock s LEFT JOIN
     conversion c 
     ON s.unit = c.unit1 AND c.unit2 = 'bottle'
GROUP BY s.product
```

Comment: Is there a way to add these extra rates on the fly such as using a View? thanks.

Comment: @Sunnyday . . . It can become rather complicated, requiring a recursive CTE of some sort.

Comment: Adding the extra rates makes it more difficult for user to manage. How about a custom function getRate(unit1, unit2)? Thanks.

Comment: @SunnyDay . . . It depends on what database you are using and how many different units you have to deal with.  A function is okay, but usually kills performance -- if the tables are large.